# Calendar in SAS/AF

Tags: calendar, sas

I would like to know if there is anybody out there who has a calendar to be used in an AF-application, where it is possible to pick a specific date.

Cheers Bill

*> Crossposted from SAS-L*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly.  Just use the Legacy (Version 6) OLE Calendar Object to embed a calendar in a SAS AF/Frame.  Then use SAS Component Language OLE functions to completely control the calendar and give it whatever functionality you would like.